# how we can show last inserted record in popup window using php mysql jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I am creating a project that contains `php` form which takes `input` from users and save it in `mysql` database. I want to show the user can view the record after submission the form without leaving the page in popup window. I know that the easiest way to do this is redirect the user to another php page to do this but I want only the record in same page and window.
I am a beginner in php.

```
<?php
$title = 'Add new member';
include_once 'header.php';
include_once 'footer.php';?>
<html>
    <body>
        <section id="main" class="column">

        <h4 class="alert_info">Welcome to the management page of the company</h4><div class="wrapper">
        <div id="main" style="padding:2px 0 0 0;">
        <article class="module width_full">
           <header><h3>Stats</h3></header>
           <div class="module_content">
        <!-- Form -->
                <form action="addmembers.php" method="post" class="register">
            <h1 style="margin-left: 250px;">New Member Registration</h1>
            <fieldset class="row1">
                <legend>Account Details
                </legend>
                <p>
                <label>
                    Introducer Id: *</label>
                    <input type="text" name="3" id="introducerid" placeholder="Please enter Introducer Id" required onKeyDown="limitText(this,6);"onKeyUp="limitText(this,6);"/>

                                <label>
                    Introducer Name: *</label>
                    <input type="text" name="42" id="Introducerame" placeholder="Please enter Introducer Name" required autofocus>

                </p>

                        </fieldset>
                        <fieldset class="row2">
                            <legend>Personal Details
                </legend>
                                <p>
                <label>
                    <span>Name: *</span></label>
                    <input type="text" name="5" id="name" placeholder="Please enter member's name" required autofocus class="long">

            </p>

                        <p>
                <label>
                    <span>Father/Husband Name: *</span></label>
                    <input type="text" name="6" id="father_husband_name" placeholder="Please enter father or husband name" required autofocus class="long">

                        </p>
            <p>
                <label>
                    <span>Correspondence Address: *</span></label>
                    <input type="text" name="7" id="per_address" placeholder="Please enter correspondence address" required autofocus class="long">

                        </p>
            <p>
                <label>
                    <span>City: *</span></label>
                    <input type="text" name="8" id="city" placeholder="Please enter city name" required class="long">
                        </p>
            <p>
                <label>
                    <span>Residential Address: *</span></label>
                    <input type="text" name="9" id="resi_address" placeholder="Please enter current address" required autofocus class="long">

            </p>
                        <p>
                <label>
                    <span>Phone: *</span></label>
                                        <input type="text" name="22" id="phone" placeholder="Please enter contact number" required class="long" onKeyDown="limitText(this,10);"onKeyUp="limitText(this,10);"/>

                        </p>
                        <p>
                <label>
                    <span>Gender: *</span></label>
                            <input type="radio" name="23" value="Male" class="gender"><label class="gender">Male</label>
                            <input type="radio" name="23" value="Female" class="gender"><label class="gender">Female</label>

                        </p>
                        <p>
                <label>
                    <span>Nominee: *</span></label>
                    <input type="text" name="55" id="nominee" placeholder="Please enter nominee name" required autofocus class="long">

            </p>
                        <p>
                <label>
                    <span>Age: *</span></label>
                            <input type="number" name="56" id="nominee" placeholder="&nbsp;&nbsp;yy" required autofocus style="width: 55px;" onKeyDown="limitText(this,2);"onKeyUp="limitText(this,2);"/>

            </p>
                        <p>
                <label>
                    <span>Relation: *</span></label>
                    <input type="text" name="57" id="nominee" placeholder="Nominee's relation" required autofocus class="long">

            </p>
                        </fieldset>
                        <fieldset class="row3">
                            <legend>Further Information
                </legend>
                            <p>


                <label>
                    PAN card: </label>
                                        <input type="text" name="bc" id="PAN" placeholder="Please enter member's PAN card no."onKeyDown="limitText(this,10);"onKeyUp="limitText(this,10);"/>

            </p>
                                <p>
                <label>
                    <span>Email: *</span></label>
                                    <input type="email" name="24" id="email" placeholder="i.e. yourname@xyz.com" class="long">

                                </p>
            <p>
                <label>
                    <span>Date of birth: *</span></label>
                                        <input type="date" name="25" id="birthdate" required autofocus>

                        </p>
                        <p>
                <label>
                    <span>Martial Status: *</span></label>
                            <input type="radio" name="26" value="Married" class="gender"><label class="gender">Married </label>
                            <input type="radio" name="26" value="Unmarried" class="gender"><label class="gender">Unmarried</label>

                        </p>
                        <p>
                <label>
                    <span>Occupation: *</span></label>
                    <input type="text" name="27" id="occupation" placeholder="Please enter occupation detail" required class="long">

                        </p>
                        <p>
                <label>
                    <span>Education: *</span></label>
                    <select name="28" id="education" class="select">
                                          <option value="0">Select one</option>
                                          <option value="Highschool">Highschool</option>
                                          <option value="Intermediat">Intermediat</option>
                                          <option value="Graduation">Graduation</option>
                                          <option value="Under Graduate">Under Graduate</option>
                                          <option value="Post Graduation">Post Graduation</option>
                                          <option value="Under Post Graduate">Under Post Graduate</option>
                                          <option value="Other">Other</option>
                                </select>
                        </p>
                        <p>
                <label>
                    <span>Nationality: *</span></label>
                    <select name="29" id="education" class="select">
                                          <option value="not selected">Select one</option>
                                          <option value="Indian">Indian</option>
                                          <option value="Non-Indian">Non-Indian</option>
                                </select>
                                </select>

                        </p>
                        <p>
                <label>
                    <span>Verification Document: *</span></label>
                                        <select name="30" id="idproof" class="select">
                                          <option value="no">Select one from below options</option>
                                          <option value="Voter Id">Voter Id</option>
                                          <option value="Ration Card">Ration Card</option>
                                          <option value="Driving License">Driving License</option>
                                          <option value="UID card">UID card</option>
                                          <option value="PAN card">PAN card</option>
                                </select>

                        </p>
                        <p>
                <label>
                    <span>Religion: *</span></label>
                                        <input type="text" name="32" id="religion" placeholder="Please enter religion" required>

                        </p>
                        </fieldset> 
            <fieldset class="row1" style="margin-top: 30px;">
                            <legend>Bank Details
                </legend>
                        <p>
                <label>
                    <span>Bank Name: *</span></label>
                    <input type="text" name="33" id="bank_name" placeholder="Please enter Bank name" required autofocus>


                <label>
                    <span>Branch: *</span></label>
                    <input type="text" name="34" id="branch" placeholder="Please enter branch name" required autofocus>

                        </p>
                        <p>
                <label>
                    <span>IFSC code: *</span></label>
                    <input type="text" name="35" id="IFSC" placeholder="Please enter IFSC code here" required autofocus>


                <label>
                    <span>Account Number: *</span></label>
                                        <input type="text" name="36" id="account_no" placeholder="Please enter member's account number" required autofocus>

                        </p></fieldset>

                        <input type="submit" value=" Submit " name="submit"/>

        </form>
        <!-- /Form -->

        </div>
                </div>
<?php
if(isset($_POST["submit"])){
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "vicky";
$password = "vicky";
$dbname = "nrj";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "INSERT INTO members (introducrid, Introducername, PAN, name, father_husband_name, per_address, city, resi_address, phone, gender, nominee, age, relation, email, birthdate, martial_status, occupation, education, nationalty, idproof, religion, bank_name, branch, IFSC, account_no)
VALUES ('".$_POST["3"]."','".$_POST["42"]."','".$_POST["bc"]."','".$_POST["5"]."','".$_POST["6"]."','".$_POST["7"]."','".$_POST["8"]."','".$_POST["9"]."','".$_POST["22"]."','".$_POST["23"]."','".$_POST["55"]."','".$_POST["56"]."','".$_POST["57"]."','".$_POST["24"]."','".$_POST["25"]."','".$_POST["26"]."','".$_POST["27"]."','".$_POST["28"]."','".$_POST["29"]."','".$_POST["30"]."','".$_POST["32"]."','".$_POST["33"]."','".$_POST["34"]."','".$_POST["35"]."','".$_POST["36"]."')";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
echo "<script type= 'text/javascript'>alert('New record created successfully');</script>";
} else {
echo "<script type= 'text/javascript'>alert('Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error."');</script>";
}

$conn->close();
}
?>  
</div>
                <div class="spacer"></div>



        </section>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function limitText(limitField, limitNum) {
    if (limitField.value.length > limitNum) {
        limitField.value = limitField.value.substring(0, limitNum);
    }
}
</script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Look into jquery Ajax.

Comment: I know that.But problem is that how we can use jquery in my page.

Comment: Write a function to get all the fields you want by id. Post or Get to a php page. Anything you echo will be returned to the Ajax function

Answer (score 0):

After executing insert query try LAST_INSERT_ID(), it will give you last inserted record id. You can fetch record by id after that. 
If you are inserting record using ajax, then returns data in json or any format you want.

Answer (score -1):

If you don't know how to use `ajax`

change your `php` code to:

```
 $introducrid = $_POST["3"];
 $Introducername = $_POST["42"];

//like wise the entire data

 $sql = "INSERT INTO members (introducrid, Introducername, PAN, name, father_husband_name, per_address, city, resi_address, phone, gender, nominee, age, relation, email, birthdate, martial_status, occupation, education, nationalty, idproof, religion, bank_name, branch, IFSC, account_no)
```

VALUES

```
('".$_POST["3"]."','".$_POST["42"]."','".$_POST["bc"]."','".$_POST["5"]."','".$_POST["6"]."','".$_POST["7"]."','".$_POST["8"]."','".$_POST["9"]."','".$_POST["22"]."','".$_POST["23"]."','".$_POST["55"]."','".$_POST["56"]."','".$_POST["57"]."','".$_POST["24"]."','".$_POST["25"]."','".$_POST["26"]."','".$_POST["27"]."','".$_POST["28"]."','".$_POST["29"]."','".$_POST["30"]."','".$_POST["32"]."','".$_POST["33"]."','".$_POST["34"]."','".$_POST["35"]."','".$_POST["36"]."')";
if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "<script type= 'text/javascript'>alert('introducrid : ".$introducrid." <br> Introducername : ".$Introducername ." ');</script>";
} else {
    echo "<script type= 'text/javascript'>alert('Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error."');</script>";
}`
```

This will just display the data you sent in an alert.

But I would recommend using ajax .

For that refer : http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/
 and http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_database.asp

Comment: Your code is susceptible to SQL injection. Please don't do that and instead use prepared statements. Also, don't use w3schools for any source of information.